# hide column for drilldown report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

How to hide columns when the drill down report is loaded first time? I have the following columns.

```
Col1    Col2     Col3    Col4
-----------------------------
+ test1    10      

+ test2    20
```

I would like to hide Col3 and Col4 on intial load of the report. When I click on + on Col1 and show Col3 and Col4. Could you please let me know any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

go into the visiblity properties of the row or column (select column, right click, visibility options) and select 'the display of this item can be toggled by the following field, and also set the field to hidden.